# Функция replace, на работает со знаком запятая в кирилице

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Столкнулся с проблемой, что создав правило замены запятой на точку функцией replace оно отлично работает с знаками латиницы, но при этом игнорирует кириллицу. Само выражение выглядит так:

```
.replace(/[^[+-]?\d+\.?\d*,]/g, '',[/,/, '.'])
```

Как его правильно дополнить и вообще возможно ли это, чтоб замена происходила и с знаком запятая в кириллице?

Comment: Ваше  регулярное выражение неверно, и функцию `replace` тоже неверно используете.

Answer (score 0):

Вот. Всё проще :) А если первым аргументом использовать именно регулярку, как тип, а не строку, то чтобы кириллица отрабатывала, надо флаг `u` еще добавить.
В общем фукция `replace()` [принимает 2 аргумента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Первый - это либо регулярка, либо строка. Второй, это то, **НА ЧТО ЗАМЕНИТСЯ** любое вхождение из этой регуляки. Если у тебя регулярка точно правильная, то будет примерно так

```
let str = 'some string';
str.replace(/[^[+-]?\d+\.?\d*,]/gu, '.');
```

То есть всё, что подпадает под эту регулярку в строке `str` будет заменено на точку `.` 
Флаги - это вот те буквы в конце регулярного выражения. `/regexp/gu`. Флаг `g` означает продолжать искать дальше, даже если нашлось одно попадание. Флаг `u` означает обрабатывать кириллицу. `i` - игнорировать регистр. [Вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) можно подробнее почитать.

```js
let str = 'asdasd, asda';

console.log(str.replace(',', '.'));
```

Comment: А можно подробнее, куда этот флаг надо подставить правильно? Просто выражение которое указанно выше использую и если переделывать его под пример то потянет еще ряд вопросов :( Спасибо, что уже хоть ясно, что это реально.

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Флаг `u` здесь не нужен, а регулярное выражение в ТС неверное, достаточно посмотреть [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/zbGyPz/1).

Comment: А за эту ссылку спасибо. Пойду попробую там чет сваять. Почитал за флаг u, он же вроде дает возможность распознавать кирилицу, собственно с ней и проблема мне так казалось, потому как запятую в английской раскладке он распознавал